# How to pass a DataTable to Mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms

I have a winforms application connected to Mysql using the .Net driver. I written a class to handle to all the database functionality. I use a dataTable to store query results for binding from mysql.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.IO

Public Class MysqlConSjC

Private conn As MySqlConnection
Private connStr As String
Public strace As String
Private status As Integer

'status member variable for connectivity. 0 for success, 
'value of one indicates db connection error
'value of 2 indicates query failure

Private comd As MySqlCommand
Private adpter As MySqlDataAdapter
Private dta As DataTable

Public Sub Query(ByVal SQl As String)

    Try
        comd.Connection = conn
        comd.CommandText = SQl
        adpter.SelectCommand = comd
        adpter.Fill(dta)
        status = 0

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        strace = ex.StackTrace()
        DisconnectMysql()
        status = 2

    End Try
   End Sub
```

This method does a select query. How would I write a method to insert/update/delete rows of the DataTable in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the provider was able to create the update statements (UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE) for the given command, then I believe you can simply call the [`Update`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update.aspx) method on the data adapter after making updates to the DataTable.

```
adapter.Update(dta)
```

The DataTable object tracks changes made to itself. The data adapter object then uses that information to determine which SQL statements (UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE) to run.

Comment: Thanks but that's the first thing I tried. I got InvalidOperationException thrown at runtime

Comment: Added adpter.updateCommand = comd so it doesn't throw that exception now but there's no update happening still

Answer (score 0):

Did the most sensible thing. I switched to the binding source control and used tableAdapters to update. A class like mine works where datagridviews are not needed